# OpenSSH Join Running Process

Tags: windows, ssh, shell

I have a Windows machine running OpenSSH so I can log in and start up a server application remotely. The application has a console window where you can type in commands.

I would like to use SSH to remotely view the already running process and issue commands. Is there an OpenSSH command for this or a workaround? Would it require a separate program or API that acts as a temporary shell for the server itself?

Alternatively, issuing commands to a running process even without viewing its output could be helpful.

Thank you,

Update: There is a solution to this for Linux called "screen", which is a terminal multiplexer allowing you to attach or detach from different sessions. No luck finding this exact functionality for Windows yet.

Comment: So the application starts a shell when you run it. do you dismiss it and logout, and then want access that shell again later? perhaps tmux or screen are a good bet for you, so you can keep the session with the application shell running in the background, and pull it back up whenever you want. Just an idea.

Comment: Ideally it would simply use OpenSSH running on Windows. I'm looking for a command to access a process that's already running and has a different HWND handle. For example, if I start up a process in the console of a laptop, close it down, and move to a PC and want to send it a different command. Using remote access software or creating a separate program, web or telnet server are options, but I would like to use SSH if possible.

Comment: you use tmux or screen within the ssh session, so that you can just reconnect from anywhere and resume that session. "accessing a process" is not a thing you can do without some kind of input to it, be it a command shell that you can launch and attach to the process, a network stream, or a file stream, or whatever. Anyway, you won't get anything specific without naming the program, as there is no generic way to open a shell to a given process, that i'm aware of. Most don't take interactive input at all.